# Xaml: design a layout with dynamically visible components

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-designer

In a mvvm application some areas inside a window (in reality it is a UserControl inside MainWindow) are dynamically displayed according to the user selections.

The changing blocks are inside Stackpanels, I have 4 of them and only one at a time is displayed. This is accomplished binding **Visibility** to a bool property and using the **BooleanToVisibilityConverter**.

I put all the alternate StackPanel inside parent control. It works correctly, but during **design phase** in Visual Studio I see all of them, so I have problems in figuring the final layout.

How can I easily create the layout having more controls which share the same window area and are displayed one at a time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setting A Design Time Only Data Context

Developing XAML in the Studio Designer can be greatly simplified by setting the Design-Time Data Context.

One implementation is based on setting a duplicate `DataContext` which will be ignored during the final compilation.

To implement the switching, add to the **ViewModel**, a property that will inform the designer whether it can be used in Development Mode or not.

---

I use an MVVMLight situation for this example, but for this declared instance property `IsInDesignMode` and static property `ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic`.

Example:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DataContextDesignTime.Example
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool _flag;
        public bool Flag
        {
            get => _flag;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_flag, value))
                {
                    _flag = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Flag)));
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(NotFlag)));
                }
            }
        }

        public bool NotFlag => !Flag;
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="DataContextDesignTime.Example.ExamleWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataContextDesignTime.Example"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ExamleWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <d:Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel Flag="True" NotFlag="True"/>
    </d:Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Border Background="LightBlue" Height="200"
                Visibility="{Binding Flag, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <Border Background="LightGreen" Height="400"
                Visibility="{Binding NotFlag, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In this example, you can change property values in XAML or in the Property Browser.
And you will immediately see the work of your bindings, triggers, how the display for certain data changes.

---

[image]

---

##### Note

This may fail on more complex VMs/packages, but in general  by setting the DataContext at design time is not difficult.

> I need to recompile the project to see the changes in the properties.

The XAML Designer panel has an «Enable/Disable Project Code» button.
[image]

Comment: I learned something today, this is a very valid alternative solution.

Comment: I need to recompile the project to see the changes in the properties. Is it the expected behavior ?
I did my tests without **MVVMLight**

Comment: It shouldn't be like that.
Even the INotyfyPropertyChanged implementation is not required to change from XAML.
This has always worked for me in VS2017 and 2019.
I have not tried it in others.

Comment: I updated Studio and sync with XAML stopped working for me too!
It looks like some settings have been changed.
Now I'm looking for what could be the problem.

Comment: I found the reason. Read the supplement to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> , but during design phase in Visual Studio I see all of them, so I have problems in figuring the final layout.

This problem is easily resolved by bringing up the `Document Outline` tab in visual studio. Once open, navigate to the visible tree and toggle the *eyeball* to visibly hide/unhide the control[s] one is not interested in; *during design time only*.

[image]

Comment: I tried but it is not what I was looking for. Toggling to hide adds **d:IsHidden="True"** to the control, which is not visible but doesn't free its area in the window. I need it to be collapsed, so controls which are below can raise and fill its area.

Comment: Then you need to temporarily change, hard code, the visibility of the top object to allow the `fill` operation to occur. That is the only option in design mode.

Comment: The other answer might be the solution you are looking for to manipulate your VM in design mode to switch on/off/hide controls.